# Structures with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

so I have a structure called Shield that has three pointers in it. I need to fill up with data one of this pointers before hand and I need to access this data inside of a constant loop. The problem that I'm having is that whenever I try and access what should be in my pointers my program crashes. This is my structure

```
struct Shield{
  esat::Vec3 *circle;
  esat::Vec2 *walls;
  bool *isActive;
};
```

where esat::Vec3 and esat::Vec2 are just structures with floats representing vectors.

I initialize my pointers inside of a function that takes as a parameter an Shield object and fill up such pointer data that I need.

```
void InitShield(Shield shield){

  shield.circle = (esat::Vec3*) malloc((KVertices + 1) * sizeof(esat::Vec3));
  shield.walls = (esat::Vec2*) malloc((KVertices + 1) * sizeof(esat::Vec2));
  shield.isActive = (bool*) malloc((KVertices + 1) * sizeof(bool));

  float angle = 6.28f / KVertices;
  for(int i=0; i<KVertices; ++i){
    (*(shield.circle + i)).x = cos(angle * i);
    (*(shield.circle + i)).y = sin(angle * i);
    (*(shield.circle + i)).z = 1.0f;
    (*(shield.isActive + i)) = true;
  }

}
```

And then I try and get access to what I supposedly stored in my pointer.

```
void DrawCircle(esat::Mat3 base, esat::Vec2 *tr_points, esat::Vec3 *circle, bool *checkActive){

  CheckShield(first_shield);
  for(int i=0; i<KVertices; ++i){
    esat::Vec3 points = esat::Mat3TransformVec3(base, (*(circle + i)));
    *(tr_points + i) = {points.x, points.y};
  }

  for(int i=0; i<KVertices; ++i){
    if((*(checkActive + i)) == true){
      esat::DrawSetStrokeColor(color.r, color.g, color.b);
      esat::DrawLine((*(tr_points + i)).x, (*(tr_points + i)).y, (*(tr_points + ((i+1)%KVertices))).x, (*(tr_points + ((i+1)%KVertices))).y);
    }
  }

}
```

This is where my program crashes. When I try and access what should be inside my circle pointer the program fails to and crashes.
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: `esat::Vec3` doesn't look valid syntax in the standard C. I'll change the tag to C++.

Comment: If you're using C++ why not simply use a standard container like `std::vector`? – Also why are you not simply using the index operator?  `*(ptr + i) == ptr[i]`

Comment: There is never a valid reason to use `malloc` in C++. Whichever textbook told you to do that, throw it away and get a better C++ textbook. This may or may not be the reason for your crash, nobody will be able to tell you the reason for your crash without a [mre].

Comment: `InitShield` needs to accept `shield` as a reference, no?

Comment: *"where esat::Vec3 and esat::Vec2 are just [...]"* -- better would be to provide definitions, which should be simple for "just" structures with floats: `struct Vec3 { float x, y, z; };`. Note that this takes less time to read (and type) than your description. **However,** even better would be eliminating these structs from your [mre], if that is possible. Does the problem remain if you replace `esat::Vec3` with `float` and eliminate your `walls` member? If so, do that as simpler examples are easier for others to analyze.

Comment: *"This is where my program crashes."* -- where exactly? Which line? What are the values of the variables used in that line (especially of your loop control variable, if the crash is inside a loop)?

Comment: _I have a structure called Shield that has three pointers in it_ Stop right there.  Read up on what the STL containers can do for you, especially `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function accepts an object of the type Shield by value.

```
void InitShield(Shield shield){
```

That is the function deals with a copy of the value of the passed argument.

Changing the copy within the function does not influence on the original object.

If you are using C++ then declare the function at least like

```
void InitShield(Shield &shield){
```

and use the operator `new` instead of calling `malloc` directly.

If you are using C then declare the function like

```
void InitShield(Shield *shield){
```

Also it is unclear why you are allocating `KVertices + 1` objects as for example

```
shield.circle = (esat::Vec3*) malloc((KVertices + 1) * sizeof(esat::Vec3));
```

But the following for loop uses only `KVertices` iterations.

```
for(int i=0; i<KVertices; ++i){
```

Comment: I think this worked! My program doesn't crash anymore, thank you. That makes a lot of sense now I see it.